# @ViewBuilder throws error when init with other properties

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, initialization

I have a custom view that makes use of the `@ViewBuilder` attribute in SwiftUI.

I also want to require some other properties in the initializer alongside the closure that build the view.

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public enum NavigationBarStyle {
    case title
    case dismiss
    case pop
    case popAndDismiss
}

public struct NavigationBar <TitleView: View>: View {
    
    //MARK: View Model
    
    @State var barStyle: NavigationBarStyle
    
    @Binding var showView: Bool
    
    @Binding var pushView: Bool
    
    var titleView: TitleView
    
    //MARK: Body
    public var body: some View {
        titleView
    }
    
    //MARK: Init
    public init(showView: Binding<Bool>?, pushView: Binding<Bool>?, style: NavigationBarStyle = NavigationBarStyle.dismiss, @ViewBuilder titleView: @escaping () -> TitleView) {
        //Compiler error in initializer
        self.titleView = titleView()
        self.barStyle = style
        self._showView = showView ?? .constant(true)
        self._pushView = pushView ?? .constant(true)
    }
    
}

struct NavigationBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationBar(showView: nil, pushView: nil) {
            Text("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

However this code produces a compiler error.

```sh
Variable 'self.barStyle' used before being initialized
```

I'm a little baffled. When I remove the `@ViewBuilder` feature from this code the initializer works.

Answer (score 2):

`barStyle` is not a normal variable. Your `barStyle` is `@State` var so you should need to use `State(initialValue:`.

```
 public init(showView: Binding<Bool>?, pushView: Binding<Bool>?, style: NavigationBarStyle = NavigationBarStyle.dismiss, @ViewBuilder titleView: @escaping () -> TitleView) {
        //Compiler error in initializer
        self.titleView = titleView()
        self._barStyle = State(initialValue: style) //< == Here
        self._showView = showView ?? .constant(true)
        self._pushView = pushView ?? .constant(true)
    }
```

Comment: That works but I would like to understand why my initializer works if I remove the @ViewBuilder feature.

Comment: My initializer also work if I provide a value like this `@State var barStyle: NavigationBarStyle = .dismiss`

Comment: for the second case, you already initialized var at the time of declaration so the compiler will not throw an error.